# Identifying a button without an ID with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm writing an automation program for an internal ticketing website system, and I've run into a wall.

I've managed to click a number of buttons on the site searching by ID but this one is a nested class and it's giving me a bit of trouble.

```
<body class = "employee transaction">
    ...
    <div id="form">
        <form onsubmit="return submitOnce();" action="labor_event.pl" method="post" name="timeclock">
            <fieldset class="hidden_input"></fieldset>
            <fieldset class="action_area">
                <div class="form_submit">
                    <input class="cancel button" type="button" onclick="self.close();" value="Cancel"></input>
```

I've searched a few different threads and most of them are suggesting to do the searching using By.CssSelector or By.XPath, however nothing is yielding results, was hoping someone here could offer some insight. Thanks!

Comment: Well what have you tried? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
By.xpath("//input[type='button' and value='Cancel']")
```